# Floating placeholder (CSS/JS/Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a field in the form, where users can enter their subdomain.

So there should be a placeholder (`.mysite.com`) and when they type - that placeholder should move to the right, but stay in the field (`mysubdomain.mysite.com`).
However the value submitted needs to be just whatever they typed (`mysubdomain`, not `mysubdomain.mysite.com`). Is that possible?

They shouldn't be able to remove it from the field.

Oh, it should also be preceeded with `http://`
For example they type `mysubdomain`, but the displayed value will be `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com` (probably what they typed will be different style).

Comment: show it in two separate fields in one row. In first field user will input, and when user starts typing something, the second field should be shown with a placeholder value as you said. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Hm.. That's a good point.. Have some `span` which contains format I want. Is there a way to show that span over the input field? (but at the same time - let user click on the field `under` it & edit it?) Perhaps listen to 'keyUp' event or something? (like pseudo input + hidden field)

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189847/is-it-possible-to-have-a-permanent-placeholder. Anyway, you should do some modifications on your own.