# Where could I store custom field attributes for a field in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I would like to be able to find a place to store custom attributes for a field in Sitecore.  For example let's say that I have a data template called ProductData.  And it has three fields:

- Title (Single line text)
- StrengthInPPM (number)
- AbsoluteStrength (number)

The two numeric fields also have a unit of measure associated with them.  The first one is ppm, the second is mg.  Eventually this data will need to be displayed on a page.  When the data is displayed on a page I would like it to display like this:

```
My Product Title
Strength In ppm: 27 ppm
Absolute Strength: 1350 mg
```

But I would like to find a way that the label for the field and the units of measure for the field could somehow be stored in Sitecore in the field definition itself.  I think the label could be stored in the field's Title attribute - right?  Is there any place that I could store the units of measure text in the field definition?  I couldn't find any sort of field that I could use for custom data that goes along with a field definition.

The reason that I am asking this is that in reality for the project I am working on the data template will probably have more like 100 fields.  It is all chemical data.  I would like to be able to write a routine that could just iterate through all of the fields, get the label, the value and the units of measure and display it all on the page.

Of course another way I could accomplish this is to put the label and units of measure information either in an external database table or in a config file or something.  But I would much rather just have it all in Sitecore.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just write units in field names as you did it for StrengthInPPM? Let all fields depending from units and associated with them in commonly specified way contain these units in their names. It would be clear in Sitecore Content Editor and easy to get these units in programming language by substing method from field name. Only keep one rule for all such field names, for example Strength**InUnits**PPM, Strength**InUnits**MG, etc. Here **InUnits** will be as placeholder for substring method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you split your product data into a main template (containing the product Title) and a secondary template called ProductProperty (containing PropertyName, PropertyValue, PropertyUnits etc). Then organise your content items as follows:

```
* Product X (uses ProductData template)
  * Property 1 (uses ProductProperty template)
  * Property 2
  * ...
```

This may seem cumbersome, but the benefits are that your content is easier to manage and you can then render this data more easily by looping over the child (ProductProperty items). You can do all this using the standard `<sc:FieldRenderer />` or `@Html.Sitecore().Field()` methods which will ensure page editor compatibility.

If you frequently have the same set of properties for your products, you could create a branch template defining this set of ProductProperty items meaning you wouldn't have to go and creating those 100 items each time you add a new product.

Comment: Yeah I definitely considered this approach.  From a data storage perspective this really makes the most sense.  However from a data entry perspective it becomes a bit of a nightmare.  Authors are expecting that they will have 1 form that they can use to fill out all of the data about a product.  With this approach users would have to perform 100 different Save operations when they create a new product instead of just filling out a single form and then saving it.

Comment: I see your point. I have seen custom field editors which manage the saving and editing of child items while editing the top-level item. This works in a similar way to Sitecore's template builder - you are editing tables of fields (sort of) and under the hood Sitecore is managing collections of child items. I will try to find an example for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you will end up using the data, or if it needs some cleverness involved for searches but to simplify your template you could consider the `Name Value List` field type. This will allow you to add an unlimited number of properties without having to define them for every template up front.

[image: Name Value List field]

The only caveat here is that the Name part of the field can only contain letter and numbers, so no spaces. You could either replace something like underscores with spaces on render, or create a custom control yourself.

If you are going to create a custom control then also take a look at the `Name Lookup Value List` - you may be able to extend one of these to fit your needs, or take inspiration from them. You may be able to create a control with three fields: selectable name lookup, manual value entry, selectable strength unit.

In any case, it should be a lot neater than creating 100 fields in your template, esp if all fields are not applicable for all products.

Comment: But this still requires the author to enter the units of measure for each Product - right?  I am looking for a solution where I can attach the units of measure string to the field definition itself.

Comment: Yes it does, but if you created a custom control based on these then you could use a lookup for them. I'll see if I can create a PoC but won't be till the weekend. Does the general concept work for you, and would be be more useful than coding 100 specific fields?

Comment: I guess I still don't understand you approach.  I want to avoid requiring the author to enter the UOM for each content item.  I would like the author to only enter the numeric value (e.g. 27).  Then when I go to display all of the fields on the page my code could get the 27 from the value and then would look at the field definition itself (from the template) and get the string for the UOM.  Make sense?  Your solution seems to require that the author enter "27 cm" or "27 ppm".

Comment: Sure, at the moment it does. But if the first field was a drop list the user could select, and the second was a free text they could enter the number in (just 27). Since the first is a drop list we could look those up from elsewhere in the tree (which you would set up) we could also store the unit measure there too. So a field lookup would store the name of the field and the unit of measure. Since the Name Value Lookup field is very dynamic you do not have to create a field for every possible type.

Comment: But I don't want the user to select the unit of measure.  I want the unit of measure to be the same for every item that uses this field.  If the user can select the unit of measure then they could mess it up and choose the wrong one.

Comment: Yes, I realise that, which is why the Label and Unit of Measure would be stored together in a lookup item. I'll try and get a sample coded up for you (but my laptop has just died so having to rebuild it at the moment...)

Comment: @CoreyBurnett I'll update the answer here tomorrow, but wrote a blog post with the specifics here: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/custom-sitecore-control-for-storing-keyvalue-data-with-lookups/

Comment: I read your blog post.  It is a good post but still doesn't really address my problem.  With your solution the user is allowed to pick whatever they want for the field.  The user could choose to only add one key-value pair even though there should be 100 field values entered.  And they would have to keep track of what they had entered.  So I don't think it would really work.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. The control could be changed to _always_ list every single lookup item, even disable the key box. You could also _super impose_ the measurement on the input box: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17190645/661447

Comment: I'm still struggling to see how your solution solves the problem.  If there is a field called LengthOfSideInFeet, then I want the user to only enter the number in Sitecore.  And I want to store the label somewhere ("Length of Side") and store the units of measure somewhere ("feet").  And I don't want the user to have to add the fields themselves or decide what the units of measure should be.  All the user should do is enter the number.  Then later I can write code that would display all of the fields with their label and their unit of measure text.

Comment: Your solution seems to require the user to decide which fields to add and which units of measure to use.  It's nice and flexible.  But I need to ensure uniformity.

Comment: No, what I am suggesting is you change the control to list all fields, currently it only shows fields with a value. instead. Adding/removing fields also much more flexible since it is driven from data source content.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett This is what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/9Cal9j3.png Code here: https://gist.github.com/jammykam/d935b2c5b6054ca10282 It gives you the ability to add more "fields" any time you need, or re-order from the content tree as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to create a custom field type to represent "number and unit" data? (I've had a quick Google, and I don't think something like this exist already - but I may be wrong) A custom field could allow you to have a single field on your Item to represent each of these pairs of data.

The field control could present a text entry control to capture the number, followed by a representation of the units. Depending on what's more appropriate for your solution, it could:

- Show a choice of units options as a dropdown, with the set of choices taken from the Source value for the Template's definition for the field.
- Not offer a choice, but take a specific unit from the field's Source configuration and then just display it after the number.

I'd suggest defining the Units as a Data Template type themselves, and creating items for "Parts Per Million" (etc) with whatever extra data that your system needs.

The field control could store both the unit and the value in the underlying data. This would allow you to iterate the fields and process each one in turn as you mentioned. The format you choose for this is up to you, but commonly XML or some other approach to structured text is used. Perhaps something like:

```
<data value="0.83" units="{d44109f3-659b-43d7-b761-a793c4e2f733}"/>
```

The value attribute stores the number entered, and the units attribute contains the Item ID of the item defining the appropriate unit data.

In the same way the Sitecore Kernel does, you can then have helper methods or classes which unpack this data when it's processed in your code, to help render it in the published website's UI.

There are plenty of resources on the Internet for how to go about creating the code for a custom field. This [Google search lists a few of them](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sitecore%20custom%20fields&rct=j) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It is my opinion that the numeric values, the units, and the labels are all content. And if they are content, they should be easily authorable by regular content authors, so don't hide these labels and units in the system. IMO, I would just make the entire line be part of the field, I'm not sure why you wouldn't, e.g.

- Title (SLT)
- Strength (SLT)
- AbsoluteStrength (SLT)

You could even set the standard values for the two latter fields like so:

- Strength In ppm: VALUE ppm
- Absolute Strength: VALUE mg

If this is not acceptable because a content author can change the label on a single instance of the item differently than another, then you may want to consider moving the labels and units into [dictionary entries](http://sitecoresolutions.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-sitecore-dictionary.html).

Comment: What I am trying to do is find a way to set an attribute on a field that is consistent throughout the entire system.  Unit of measure is just one example.  That way whenever I output the value from that field I can also get the attribute (or attributes) that go with that field.  I want the data input to be as simple as possible.  I don't want to let authors mess things up and enter the wrong unit of measure (or other attributes).  These attributes will very rarely change. So it is not super important to me that they be easily modified in Sitecore.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett How about something similar to what I suggested, but make the Key field the lookup and the Value field numeric only. In the lookup Key item you could store the text to display and the unit of measure. Essentially a reverse control of the `Name Lookup Value List`