# How should I store some custom attributes for an item in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm importing thousands of products from an XML feed, into Sitecore. So I created a template for the Product, which contains about 20 fields like `Identification`, `Name`, `Price` and so on.
But also, in the XML, a product can have some custom attributes, that look like this:

```
<custom-attribute name="AC_Information_1_Name" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="nl-NL">PDF</custom-attribute>
```

At first, I created a new template that would hold these fields and store a Sitecore item for each of these Custom Attributes, in a folder and link them to the Product. But this made the import really really slow, as the folder containing the Custom Attribute items had over 100 000 of them and everytime it had to save another one, it would look into all of the existing ones to check if it's not a duplicate.
So I thought I needed to change the whole structure of how I was saving these.
Another idea was to save them directly in the Product somehow, but a Name Value List was not sufficient, as there was also the `DataType` and `Language`, that needed to be saved.

Do you know any data type that could hold all the values? Or maybe some other ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it seems to be along the same lines as yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728127/where-could-i-store-custom-field-attributes-for-a-field-in-sitecore/28740870

Comment: Why did you make a repo for the custom attributes? Is it required that you can compare or enforce a relationship between products?

Comment: @RvanDalen i didn't wanted to have duplicates

Comment: You could have the type properties and value in one template and store them under the product instead of having a single attribute type list. But this is one of the solutions given in the link @IanGraham gave you. I think that post gives you great options.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Increase performance by doing your lookups against the index.
2. Look at using a bucket for your custom attributes, which will automatically create a hidden tree structure for your items to optimize Sitecore performance.
3. Consider storing it on the product as a custom field type (possibly storing XML as the raw value), much like how presentation details work. You can build a UI on top of this to show the data however you would like. This will mean duplicate data, however, but will be efficient to import.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions :

1 - Create a template for custom attribute with (Name, Value, Language, Type) and add xml's custom attributes as child item for the product.  You shouldn't need to do the look-up as the attributes should only be for the product and having them in a general folder location adds no value. So your tree might look like

Product 1 > attribute 1 | attribute 2 | .... | attribute n 
Product 2 > attribute 1 | ... 
...
Product N

2 - Create Custom field type for the xml's attribute so that your field should have 4 input boxes as one field. For example, your product template will look like

Identification 
[input box]

Price 
[input box]

Custom Attribute
Name        | Value       | Type        | Lang 
[input box] | [input box] | [input box] | [input box]

This approach will take more time and you can check out sdn documentation for creating custom field types.

Thanks 
Naveed.